# Getting started tour included in setup

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-installer, setup-project

I created a MSI set up, I want to add a tutorial "getting started" to my setup, like DropBox show tour after installation, can anybody help me?

Comment: How did you create the MSI? A simple solution is to add a custom action to your MSI to launch a custom "Getting Started" executable; the precise way you wire that up will depend on how you're creating the MSI.

Comment: I'd make the tour part of the program (check on first launch). I hate it when installers contain information that I would like to (re)view later

Comment: I used VS 2008 setup and deployment project type  and create msi, i like the way dropbox show "getting started tour" after installation, i want to do same functionality but dont know how to do it

Comment: Thanks for you helps, @Emo, i go with your way , i add a form containing images and text like slide show, and make it to run only once after installation.

Answer (score 1):

Create a simple forms application as part of your project and then like the comments say, create a custom action that launches the executable after installation.  Then, if you want to revisit the help application again, write a process start method to start the executable from the application:

```
Process.Start("C:\\EXECUTABLE.exe");
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, but i done it, i add a form containing images and text like slide show, and make it to run only once after installation.